# Не могу отловить нажатие кнопки

Tags: php, jquery

Вывожу в цикле кнопки

```
case "SqlPersonalClothing": 
    $data = $_POST;
    $f1 = " and `Department` = ".$data['f1'];
    $f2 = " and `date1` LIKE '%".$data['f2']."'";
    $f3 = " and `date1` LIKE '%".$data['f3']."%'";
   $SqlPersonalClothing = "SELECT `IdPersonal`,`Surname`,`Name` ,`MiddleName` ,`NameArea` ,`Name1` ,`quantity` ,`comment` ,`date1` ,`TimeN` ,`dateNext` FROM `Area`,`PersonalClothing`,`Clothing`,`TypeClothing`,`Employees` WHERE `IdWorker1`=`idWorker` and `IdType` = `Type` and `idClothing1` = `idClothing` and `Department`= `IDArea` ".$f1.$f2.$f3." ORDER BY Surname";
    // Подготавливаем PDO выражение для SQL запроса

$stmt = $db->prepare($SqlPersonalClothing);
$stmt->execute();
// Получаем данные SQL запроса
while ($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
    {
    Echo '<tr class="anchor" id="PersonalClothing_'.$res['IdPersonal'].'">
            <td class="td">' . $res['Surname'] . '</td>
            <td class="td">' . $res['Name'] . '</td>
            <td class="td">' . $res['MiddleName'] . '</td>
            <td class="td">' . $res['NameArea'] . '</td>
            <td class="td">' . $res['Name1'] . '</td>
            <td class="plan td">' . $res['quantity'] . '</td>
            <td class="fact td">' . $res['Fact'] . '</td>
            <td class="td">' . $res['comment'] . '</td>
            <td class="td">' . $res['date1'] . '</td>
            <td class="td">' . $res['TimeN'] . '</td>
            <td class="dateNext td">' . $res['dateNext'] . '</td>
            <td ><button class="art" value="' . $res['IdPersonal'] . '">Получил</button></td>
        </tr>';
    }; 
break;
```

пытаюсь отловить нажатие

```
 $('#pars').click(function () {
        var Year = $("#Year").val();
        var Month = $("#Month").val();
        var ValSelectDepartment = $("#SelectDepartment").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../ajax.php?Action=SqlPersonalClothing',
            data: {
                f1: ValSelectDepartment,
                f2: Year,
                f3: Month
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#PersonalClothingTable').html('<tr class="MainLine" ><th>Фимилия</th><th>Имя</th><th>Отчество</th><th>Отдел</th><th>С/О</th><th>План</th><th>Факт</th><th>Комментарий</th><th>Дата получения</th><th>Срок носки</th><th>дата след. получения</th></tr>' + result);
            }

        });

    })
```

`$('.art').click(function(){
   console.log("gg");})`

Ничего в консоль не пишется.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас присваивание функции click идет раньше, чем появляются кнопки (ваш код находится выше, чем цикл для создания кнопок), проверьте, может быть это вам поможет.

Comment: Тут тоже всё в порядке, сначала идёт ajax запрос, после него событие клик, пробывал вынести console.log за событие в document.ready Всё отлично работает

Comment: Ну, тут есть вероятность того, что ajax запрос ассинхронный, и получается, что кнопок может не быть, а клик к ним биндится. Добавьте больше кода с вашим ajax и с циклом добавления элементов в том порядке, в котором они встречаются в вашем коде.

Comment: Добавил код. Нажатие кнопки .art находиться под завершением второго блока

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.art').on('click', function(){
   console.log("gg");
})
```

Comment: Тоже безрезультатно

Comment: Всё остальное в скрипте работает